# Is there a way to animate the expansion of the div with collection of the items?

Tags: reactjs, animation

I have a collections of items and a toggler button. When I press the button "Show more", the number of items in the collection is changing and the height of the collection's container is increasing.
[image]
Is there a way to animate this with just CSS of using some animation library? I need a smooth way to do it, because now the blocks below are shifting harshly and it looks not good at all.

I am using React, here is the my sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-collection-length-changing-5ri2oj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Story:** For this use-case I was able to animate with Plain JS and CSS. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-collection-length-changing-forked-y3h0uu?file=/src/App.js 

 **Long Story:**  
When it comes to react you have number of options in animating,

1. Using Plain Old CSS and JS fix - For beginners I would suggest this as this will help you learn css, animation and transition properties. The trick is start with [Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) property. Once you moved past this you can start consuming  [Animations.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) 

   When it comes to your case, using `transition` property was enough. I've played with height property and was able to achieve  [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-collection-length-changing-forked-y3h0uu?file=/src/App.js). You can also using `opacity` clubbed with `height` property. I've seen somecases use `max-height` property. You can refer one such [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp).
2. Using React Libraries, a number of React libraries are available for animations, naming some here - 
    [React Motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion),  [Framer](https://www.framer.com/motion/) 
   I would suggest you to compare the n-number of libraries available and select the one that suits your needs. You can start [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/best-react-animation-library-top-7-libraries-compared/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I needed, using just JS works great. Just one more question for your solution, why do you use initLengthRef to store length and not just local state?

Comment: Hi, Refs are usually used in places when you need to store value that doesn't change between React Lifecycles. If you are to define a variable the value is re-initialized every time component is re-render which is alot. And hence this is followed as a convention by React Dev. 

Also, one more note this example is just an idea. I wouldn't call it production ready as it still has some bugs.